# What type and size of paper, and corresponding to which modern font, would have been used for typewriters in 1896?

Tags: technology, north-america, historical-techniques

I am going to be doing a first-person performance of an 1896 lecture; the subject being "impersonated" (Mark Twain) sometimes carried sheaves of paper onto the platform; some of these sheets contained hand-drawn "hieroglyphics" to remind him of what he was going to talk about and in which order, but some probably contained type-written excerpts from his works.

To make the presentation as accurate and realistic as possible, what sort of paper should I use (thick stock, off white?); what size? 8.5 X 11, or something else?

Finally, what modern font would be similar to the typewritten characters of the day - Courier? What font size - 12?

Comment: Try contacting [TYPEWRITER MUSEUM](http://www.mrmartinweb.com/type.htm). They have an 1896 typewriter - the web site does not mention the fonts or paper sizes.

Comment: Also see [The Classic Typewriter Page.](http://site.xavier.edu/polt/typewriters/index.html)